# H2O XGBoost bug and OS limitation

Tags: h2o

I have two questions.

1)
I'm testing H2O 3.10.5.1 version for xgboost modeling.
There is a known bug (PUBDEV-4585) that binary save/load of xgboost doesn't work.
Has it been fixed in the recent version? Confirmation is needed in order to make a decision with the server admin whether to upgrade the system or not.

2)
H2O.ai xgboost documentation says there is some limitation to platforms.
The "compilation OS" is Ubuntu 14.04, but is there a limitation to any other linux OS version like Redhat?
h2o.xgboost.available() returns TRUE but I need to make sure.

Thanks

Comment: i would advise testing the exact versions you are considering of linux and h2o together with docker before “committing” to that install.  the xgboost support is the trickiest thing in h2o, in terms of platform support.

Answer (score 2):

Ad.1 Yes it's been fixed in version 3.18.0.1

Ad.2 The distro itself isn't really important. It's more important which exact version of RedHat are we talking about (since different versions come bundled with different lib versions) and whether you can upgrade libraries on your own if necessary. For example if you want to run the GPU version you'll need a certain version of glibc (2.17 or never if I remember correctly). For the CPU version most recent Linux distributions should be ok.